# Trouble with Background Video- Safari Only- full width & full height

Tags: css, video, safari, background

I am only seeing the issue in Safari, both Chrome and Firefox work as needed. It seems that in Safari it is loading the .video-container > video height:100% but not the width:100%. Has anyone had this issue or know a possible solution?

Site build URL: http://betterbrands.3rfocuslabs.com

My Styles:

```
video#bgvid {
background: url(images/home/bg-video.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
.video-container {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
}
.video-container > video {
display: block;
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index: 1;
}
@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 1920/1080) {
.video-container > video {
height: 100%;
}
}
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 1920/1080) {
.video-container > video {
width: 100%;
}
}
```

My Code:

```
<div class="video-container">
<video autoplay loop muted poster="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/home/bg-video.jpg" id="bgvid">
<source src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/video/beer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/video/beer.ogg" type="video/ogg">
<source src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/video/beer.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
</div>
```

Comment: Can anyone point me toward a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Safari with viewport units (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=145614). I guess it's a bug overall. 
Seems they started to support this feature this May only. So issues are possible.
https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units
Check known issues and browser version support.

Comment: Based on the site you linked it appears that Safari 11.1 is supported, and there don't appear to show any known issues for it.

Comment: Here is a Screenshot of the site you mentioned: https://imgur.com/723ns8p. And here is a screenshot of the issue i'm having and showing that I do have Safari 11.1: https://imgur.com/JcciLMb